# declared Swift empty Array is treated as NSArray if i am not giving type annotation

Tags: arrays, swift

While I am playing with Swift Array I came across a problem.
Here below is my experiment:

```
var iArray = [] //Here if I see the type details in quick help it is of NSArray type.

var myArray = [Int]() //Here if I see the type details in quick help it is of Swift Array<Int> type.
```

Now if I check like below

```
if iArray is NSArray { //it gives error saying it is always true, which is correct.
   println("Confused")
}
if iArray is Array<String> { //Here it is true and printing the message and same is also true if i check for Array<Int>
   println("More Confused")
}
```

As per documentation, Swift Arrays are equivalent to `NSArray`. Should I understand that quick help is giving wrong information? More explanation would be great at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var iArray = []
```

creates an empty `NSArray`. (This array is pretty useless because `NSArray`
is immutable, so you cannot add any elements to it.)

```
if iArray is Array<String> { ... }
```

checks if *each* element in the array is (or can be bridged to) a `String`.
The array has no elements, therefore the check succeeds
– a ["vacuous truth"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).
If you change your code to `var iArray : NSArray = [ 1 ]` then this
check would fail.

A forced cast would succeed as well:

```
for s in iArray as! Array<String> {
    println(s.lowercaseString)
}
```

and that is no problem because the loop body is never executed.

Comment: Thanks, From your code var iArray : NSArray = [ 1 ], it is expected to fail the check - if iArray is Array<String> {} because it is holding integers. As per my understanding  var iArray = [] is of type Array<AnyObject> . Do you think quick help is giving wrong information ?

Comment: @Amit89: `var iArray = []` is just an `NSArray` and that does have any information about the types of its elements. NSArray is not *identical* to a Swift array, it is "automatically converted".

Comment: @Amit89: Does that answer your question now?

Comment: Your explanation is valid, and what i understood is quick help is wrong.