# How to add multiple paramaters[String,Dictionary] in a dictionary using swift?

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am building iOS Application using Swift.I am using XCODE version 6.3.
I want to post data to server using JSON.For that i created a dictionary for performing the following operation.

```
//This is my dictionary right now
 var parameters = ["authenticity_token":name,"platform":"mobileApp", "email": userEmail, "password": userPassword,"remember_me":"1"]

 request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &err)
```

I want to pass data as the format shown below.

```
{"authenticity_token":"token","platform":"mobileApp",
"user":{"email":"email_id", "password":"123456",
 "remember_me":"1"}}
```

Right now parameter dictionary in the Format

```
[platform: mobileApp, authenticity_token: a1oj3olt5jn169LHn59ZbfbrBVUyov7sDVHlOl+2YzE=, email: su@gmail.com, remember_me: 1, password: samrat]
```

order of the paramater also changed.
I want to pass  to my dictionary.
Or is there any possibility to add two dictionaries.

This is my code for posting data to server.I have another confusion whether it is correct or not.

```
 func postData()
  {
     let name = defaults.stringForKey("secretKey")

    var parameters = ["authenticity_token":name,"platform":"mobileApp", "email": userEmail, "password": userPassword,"remember_me":"1"]

    println("Dic\(parameters)")
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://behance.moblearn.net/users/sign_in")
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &err)

     let jsonStr = NSString(data: request.HTTPBody!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    println("Post Method reached")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    println("Response: \(response)")
    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("Body: \(strData)")
    var err: NSError?
    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

      if(err != nil) {
        println(err!.localizedDescription)
        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
    }
    else {

        if let parseJSON = json {
            var success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
            println("Succes: \(success)")
        }
        else {
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
        }
    }
})
task.resume()
}
```

I am in deep trouble.I am Beginner in swift.Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this:

```
let innerDict = ["email": "email_id", "password": "123456", "remember_me": "1"]
let mainDict = ["authenticity_token": "token", "platform": "mobileApp", "user": innerDict]
```

Comment: How do you see it working — mixing Dictionary objects and Strings in one dictionary without providing Dictionary Type definition?

Comment: @NikitaLeonov The compiler will infer the type of mainDict as "NSDictionary", which doesn't carry type information. Extracting an object from this dictionary will return `AnyObject?`.

Comment: @Aderstedt each day I am learning something new. Thanks. Apparently it is like you explained — http://swiftstub.com/667283248/?v=gm Taking back my -1. 
ps Will do so as soon as answer will be edited at least once.

Comment: @Amit Anyway i really like your answer

Comment: @NikitaLeonov It should work, If you know/heard the word "type infer", you can understand clearly.

Comment: @NikitaLeonov Check this link, how it happens. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878770/declared-swift-empty-array-is-treated-as-nsarray-if-i-am-not-giving-type-annotat

Comment: @Amit89 can you do dummy edit of your answe? I need to "revote"